# Embed error in serverinfo command Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm getting an error in my embed saying that embed field values can't be empty strings, but I don't see why they're empty. Please help me out.

***My code:***

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'serverinfo',
    description: 'Returns information about the server.',
    async execute(interaction) {
        const guild = interaction.guild

    const owner = interaction.guild.fetchOwner()    
    let guildDescription = guild.description
    if (!guildDescription) {
      guildDescription = 'None'
    }

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('serverinfo')
    .setDescription('Returns information about the server.')
    .addFields({
                name: 'Name',
                value: guild.name,
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'ID',
                value: guild.id,
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Description',
                value: guildDescription,
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Created at',
                value: guild.createdAt.toDateString(),
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Owner',
                value: owner.tag,
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Member Count',
                value: guild.memberCount.toString(),
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Member Cap',
                value: guild.maximumMembers.toString(),
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Boosts',
                value: guild.premiumSubscriptionCount.toString(),
                inline: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Boost Level',
                value: guild.premiumTier,
                inline: true
              })

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
    },
};
```

***My error:***

```
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
    at Function.verifyString (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:413:41)
    at Function.normalizeField (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:19)
    at /home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:464:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:463:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/home/runner/MultiBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:286:42)
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/MultiBot/commands/serverinfo.js:19:6)
    at Object.execute (/home/runner/MultiBot/events/interactionCreate.js:11:66)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MultiBot/index.js:16:44)
```

Comment: Posting junk to bypass the quality filter is not likely to earn you any upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`Guild.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). As I see from your code, the `execute()` function is already `async`. So you will likely want to use `await`.

```js
const owner = await interaction.guild.fetchOwner();
```

Also `owner` is an instance of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), which has no property `.tag`. Use `GuildMember`'s `.user` property to access the tag.

```js
// ... Rest of the fiels ...
{
    name: 'Owner',
    value: owner.user.tag,
    inline: true
},
// ... Rest of the fiels ...
```